# Nested listview for multidimensional array

Tags: listview, nativescript-vue

I have a json where many teams have many members and I don't know haw to display it with a ListView. I've tried nested ListView but the loop stops after one member.

This is the json structure

```
[
    {
        "name": "Red Team",
        "members": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "role": "Member"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mike",
                "role": "President"
            }
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Green Team",
        "members": [
            {
                "name": "Alan",
                "role": "Member"
            },
            {
                "name": "Adam",
                "role": "President"
            }
            ...
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

This is my code

```js
<StackLayout>
    <Label class="message" text="Team" />
    <ListView for="teams in teamMembers">
        <v-template>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label :text="teams.name" />
                <ListView for="member in teams.members">
                    <v-template>
                        <Label :text="member.name" />
                    </v-template>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </v-template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: If the number of members is limited to not too many per team, I would just ditch the nested list view and just put a v-for on the member name label inside the v-template.

Comment: mmmm... I could try... but do you think I can get the same result with a RadListView plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with an intermediate page of teams and then a page o team's members.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Nativescript-Vue you can create custom components.
Using a custom component to create the template for your members.

IE. Template in component with prop team:

```
        <StackLayout>
            <Label :text="team.name" />
            <ListView for="member in team.members">
                <v-template>
                    <Label :text="member.name" />
                </v-template>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label class="message" text="Team" />
    <ListView for="team in teamMembers">
        <v-template>
            <TeamMembers :team="team"/>
        </v-template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

I think this will work in your case.